# bind mounting a volume in docker fails with lxc-start: No such file or directory

Tags: docker

If I try to bind mount an external volume into an image, I sometimes see this:

lxc-start: No such file or directory - failed to mount '/var/genapp/apps/300a6641/blah' on '/usr/lib/lxc/rootfs///blah'
lxc-start: failed to setup the mount entries for …

this was working until I upgraded to 0.7.2

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the directory does not exist in the image. Create a new image that has the /blah directory in it and it will work.